# Extracting just the words from a text file

Tags: linux, unix

What's the Unix command to take a text file and strip away whitespace and punctuation, leaving only the words, one word per line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is already answered [here on stackoverflow for shell commands that does this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123572/extract-words-from-a-file).

Alternatively you can [also use vim to do this as outlined in this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357045/convert-file-one-word-per-line).

**The top answer given by rampion on how to using shell:**

---

You could use `grep`:

- `-E '\w+'` searches for words
- `-o` only prints the portion of the line that matches

```
% cat temp
Some examples use "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog,"
rather than "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
for example text.
# if you don't care whether words repeat
% grep -o -E '\w+' temp
Some
examples
use
The
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
the
lazy
dog
rather
than
Lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
consectetur
adipiscing
elit
for
example
text
```

If you want to only print each word once, disregarding case, you can use `sort`

- `-u` only prints each word once
- `-f` tells `sort` to ignore case when comparing words

```
# if you only want each word once
% grep -o -E '\w+' temp | sort -u -f
adipiscing
amet
brown
consectetur
dog
dolor
elit
example
examples
for
fox
ipsum
jumped
lazy
Lorem
over
quick
rather
sit
Some
text
than
The
use
```

---